# Make sure PipedOutputStream blocks (flush?)

Tags: java, multithreading, inputstream, outputstream

I am using `PipedOutputStream` and `PipedInputStream` in Java.

One thread is generating bytes and writing them; the other is consuming them.

I want to make sure that I don't generate bytes significantly faster than I can consume them.

When does `PipedOutputStream` block? Is there a fixed size to its buffer?

Or do I need to call `flush()` everytime after I `write()`?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11404720/2071828) seems to mainly answer this question. Not really a dup though.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, that does seem to answer it.

Comment: Worth taking a look at the [Javadoc for `PipedInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html).

Comment: @BoristheSpider, I read that, though I did not realize the buffer of the `PipedInputStream` was also shared by the `PipedOutputStream`. (Makes sense, in hindsight.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how it already behaves. The pipes share a rather small buffer, 1k according to the comments below, and if it fills up the writer blocks.

Comment: Looks like [1k](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.io.PipedInputStream.PIPE_SIZE) to me. Not sure if that's the right constant though.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, I agree.